# Template class using itself as argument. C++

Tags: c++, templates, arguments

I'm a newbee in programming and trying to understand why this code doesn't compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

template <class T>
class Parent {
    protected:
        std::set<T*>* list;
    public:
        Parent() {
            list = new std::set<T*>;
        }
        ~Parent() {}
};

int main() {
    Parent<Parent>* f = new Parent<Parent>;

    return 0;
}
```

I have such errors:

```
test5.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test5.cpp:23:18: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter
list for 'template<class T> class Parent'
test5.cpp:23:18: error:   expected a type, got 'Parent'
test5.cpp:23:23: error: invalid type in declaration before '=' token
test5.cpp:23:42: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter
list for 'template<class T> class Parent'
test5.cpp:23:42: error:   expected a type, got 'Parent'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Note you're leaking the memory that stored `list`. You should put `delete list` in the destructor of `Parent`

Comment: @RobinHartland: Or even better yet, not use dynamic allocation at all when it's clearly not necessary. (Strictly speaking, there is not even a *leak* in this simple test program because the memory usage is constant.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting it wrong, compiler has no way to deduce type T during compilation. There is no type Parent, there are types Parent where T can be whatever you want, int, class whatever so for example

```
Parent< int >* f = new Parent< int >();
```

or ( It depends what this list is supposed to do, but if you want set of the same objects )

```
template <class T>
class Parent {
    protected:
        std::set< Parent<T> *>* list;
    public:
        Parent() {
            list = new std::set< Parent< T >*>;
        }
        ~Parent() {}
};
```

I assumed that you are aware of memory leak caused by set allocation and possible one because of pointers to elements of set ...

Comment: Regarding your last sentence: Again, this is *not* strictly a memory leak in this simple test program because the memory usage is constant. It would be a real memory leak if, for example, multiple instances were created in a loop and the number of iterations would depend on user input. I think the biggest problem is that the OP has used dynamic allocation in the first place and may not be aware that unlike almost all other mainstream languages, object construction in C++ requires `new` only for special use cases. The missing `delete`s seem to be a side effect of general unfamiliarity with C++.

Comment: @Christian Hackl So I am only reminding and yes it is good practice to avoid new operator, however it is good habit to take care about it even in test programs, I agree with you all in the line btw :)  BR, Robert

Comment: @RobertWadowsky: Yes and no. I think it's a good habit for new programmers when they learn about dynamic allocation, but it's not a strict dogma. Some C++ idioms depend on `new`ed objects never being deleted, e.g. safe singleton implementations without order-of-destruction issues.

Comment: @Christian Hackl Well lets agree to disagree, It seems more theoretic topic :)

Answer (score 0):

Because `Parent` is not a class but a class template. It **generates** classes.

It's for the same reason that you cannot have a `std::vector<std::vector> v;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can overcome this template vs class tension by introducing the actual class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

template <class T>
class Parent {
    protected:
        std::set<T*>* list;
    public:
        Parent() {
            list = new std::set<T*>;
        }
        ~Parent() {}
};

class Child : public Parent<Child> {
};

int main() {
    Child* f = new Child();

    return 0;
}
```

Now `Child` is a class you can instantiate. It *has* a `list` of objects of type `Child`.

Comment: While this works, I'm not sure it solves the OP's problem, because the OP has not really given us a problem statement other than asking why compilation failed.

Comment: You were closest to my problem, because my question came from your example. I tested code like yours before asking and it worked. But i didn't understand why i can't to do  like in my question... Now its clear. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

in fact, you have no way to define `Parent<Parent>`;the right way may look like  `Parent< Parent<Parent< Parent <` ,it has no end.